# How to enable writing to coreduetd.log

Tags: macos, logs

In Yosemite, there is a log file here:

```
/private/var/log/coreduetd.log
```

...but it's always empty.
How do I make the system write events to it, assuming there are any?

Comment: I'm willing to start a bounty on this question, if it looks promising that it can be answered.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you know that you've tinkered with the permissions on the file, it should be:

> -rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  0 Oct 18 11:02 /private/var/log/coreduetd.log

This logfile is empty on the 5 Yosemite Macs I have access to.

Comment: That's my experience as well and looking at CoreDuet's database, I see mentioned: power, thermal, sleep/wake events, etc..  I've also run all sorts of tests (e.g. memory_pressure) and would at some point expect content, if writing was enabled.  There also is a private framework, which seems to be for debug logging (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuetDebugLogging.framework) and I would hope there is a way to enable logging in a way to find content in this log.